# How to make flag (using flag-icon-css) fill table cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `flag-icon-css` on a site.

Here is the generated HTML table row:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.3.1/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Location</th>
      <th class="text-center">Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/view?+16466635449">(646) 663-5449</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I make the flag larger so it looks more normal, according to the `flag-icon-css` it should automatically behave in this way?

Looking for a solution without using custom CSS.

This site is using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are still here.. you should use the `flag-icon-background` instead of `flag-icon` and add it to the parent which is your case is `<td>`:

```
<td class="flag-icon-background flag-icon-us"></td>
```

And here is the full example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.3.1/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Location</th>
      <th class="text-center">Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="flag-icon-background flag-icon-us"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/view?+16466635449">(646) 663-5449</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think he ment dynamically as I am looking to ahieve the same thing I have my flag bound to a model property called flag

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can target `flag-icon` class in your CSS and add the `font-size`and it will make flag larger.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a hack. Any way I can just make the flag relative to the height of the button in the second column in the same row?